# ViewPager with PagerAdapter Not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to show images from **Drawable** in view pager using PagerAdapter for that, I have written below code--

**// Call to the PagerAdapter**

```
public void showAwardsBadgesAlert() 
    {
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.MyAlertDlgTheme);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.awards_badges_dlg_layout);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        ViewPager awardsBadgesPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.awardsBadgesPager);

        AwardsBadgesAdapter awardsBadgesAdapter = new AwardsBadgesAdapter(context, feedObject.getAwardStatistics().getAwardsBdgesList());
        awardsBadgesPager.setAdapter(awardsBadgesAdapter);

        dialog.show();
    }
```

**// Below is my Adapter Class--**

```
public class AwardsBadgesAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<AwardsBadges> awardsList;

    public AwardsBadgesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AwardsBadges> awardsList) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.awardsList = awardsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        if(awardsList != null)
        {
            return awardsList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final View container, final int position) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.awards_badges_dlg_item, null);

        ImageView ivAwards = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ivAwardsBadges);

        AwardsBadges currBadge = awardsList.get(position);

        if(currBadge.getImageName()!=null && currBadge.getImageName().equalsIgnoreCase("pink star diamond"))
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.pinkstar).into(ivAwards);
        }
        else if(currBadge.getImageName()!=null && currBadge.getImageName().equalsIgnoreCase("tanzanite"))
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.tanzanite).into(ivAwards);
        }
        else if(currBadge.getImageName()!=null && currBadge.getImageName().equalsIgnoreCase("painite"))
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.painite).into(ivAwards);
        }
        else if(currBadge.getImageName()!=null && currBadge.getImageName().equalsIgnoreCase("taaffeite"))
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.taaffeite).into(ivAwards);
        }


        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) 
    {
        return (0.33f);
    }
}
```

**// Below is my dialog xml--**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/awardsBadgesPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sz_seventy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPlace"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/tipstransperent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**// Below is ViewPager Item xml--**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAwardsBadges"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sz_fifty"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sz_fifty"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**// Below is the screen shot explaining currently how it is showing empty ViewPager--**

[image]

When I debug the app everything seems fine but don't know why Images are not getting displayed in ViewPager. Please Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

((ViewPager) container).addView(layout);
Add above statement in your **instantiateItem()** method, **before the return statement.** This will surely help you.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should be overriding the `instantiateItem()` method with `ViewGroup` as the first parameter, not the one with `View` as the first parameter. The latter is deprecated.

Then, you need to add your inflated `View` to the `container` in the  `PagerAdapter`'s `instantiateItem()` method. Quoting the docs for the [`instantiateItem()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#instantiateItem(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)):

> The adapter is responsible for adding the view to the container given here

Simply add `container.addView(layout);` to the `instantiateItem()` method, before the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried this but it is giving "The method addView(View) is undefined for the type View" Error..

Comment: @DnyaneshM Please read the first sentence in my answer. If you use the correct method, then `container.addView(layout)` will work without having to cast `container`. The `addView()` method is defined for ViewGroup.

Comment: Do you follow me? All you have to do is change the `instantiateItem()` method's first parameter from `final View container` to `final ViewGroup container`.